# Transfer file from Windows to VMware linux client

Tags: linux, windows, vmware

I have a Windows 7 host that runs a VMware RedHat Enterprise Linux 6.3 client (which has been modified and given to me as an .iso). Instead of being shown a graphical interface, I just have access to a command prompt as `root`.

I need to copy and execute a `.bin` file in Linux-land, but the file currently lives in Windows-land. How can I get the file into Linux-land?

My first thought was to use VMware tools, but installation of those fail with an "internal error". My second thought was to use `ftp`, but my shell does not have the `ftp` command. I also have three network interfaces `eth0`, `eth1` and `eth2` but I have no idea how to make use of those. I also had a quick look at Samba, but my prompt does not support the command `smbpasswd`. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Edit:** Folder sharing does not seem possible either.

[image]

Comment: The simplest solution would be to figure out the reason your getting an error when you install VM Tools.  This is the reason shared folders is likely disabled currently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could ...

1. Ensure sshd is running on the Linux VM
2. Download and use WinSCP or Putty's pscp on the Windows host

Comment: Thanks. I have `sshd` and Putty. You're talking to a network noob though; how exactly should I drive those tools?

Comment: Syntax: `C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe d:\my_file_I_want_to_transfer.bin server.mydomain.tld:` (do not forget the `:`).

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this, a few of these are:

**From the Windows  host:**
`C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe d:\my_file.bin server.mydomain.tld:`
(Or any other scp client, such as winscp if you want a GUI)

This assumes sshd is running, but I have yet to run into the first VM which has that disabled

**From the Linux host:**
Put the files on a web server and download them.
`wget http://windowsserver.domain.tld/myfile.bin` or
`curl http://windowsserver.domain.tld/myfile.bin`

Skip old fashioned regular FTP if at all possible. It is ancient and its design shows it (e.g. firewall problem unless you run in passive mode, plain text authentication, ...).

An even better method would be to discover why shared folders/ vmware tools have problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared folder feature:

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html

Edit:
There are lot of ways to share a file. You could have a http server running on your host and use wget; You could run ssh server on guest and use scp to copy, etc. It sounds like to me you need to familiar yourself with Linux system a bit.

Comment: This does not seem possible here. Please see the screenshot.